# Echo An Array inside a EOF statement

Tags: php, arrays, eof

I'm trying to send an HTML email receipt from a shopping cart purchase but I don't get how to echo the session array within the EOF area. php doesn't seem to want to execute here. Thoughts?

```
//begin of HTML message
$message = <<<EOF
<html>
<body style="font-family: 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;     
font-size:10px;"><center>


<table width="750" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="view-cart" style="text-    
align:center;padding:5px;"><tr>
<tr><td>Image</td><td>SKU</td><td>Description</td><td>QTY</td><td>Price</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>

     foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
            echo '<td><img src="'.$cart_itm['image'].'"></td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<div class="p-code">'.$cart_itm["code"].'</td>';
            echo '<td align="left">'.$cart_itm["description"].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cart_itm["qty"].'</td>';
            echo '<td><div class="p-price">'.$cart_itm["price"].' each</div></td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

    </table>


</center>
</body>
</html>

EOF;
//end of message
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The updated code now looks like this. I replaced the "$message +=" with "$message .=" and it seems to work fine now. :

```
 //begin of HTML message
 $message = <<<EOF
 <html>
  <body style="font-family: 'Myriad Pro', 'DejaVu Sans Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px;"><center>


 <table width="750" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="view-cart" style="text-align:center;padding:5px;">
 <tr><td>Image</td><td>SKU</td><td>Description</td><td>QTY</td><td>Price</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>

 EOF;

foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) 
 {
            $message .= "<td><img src=".$cart_itm['image'].">";
            $message .= "</td><td>".$cart_itm['code'];
            $message .= "</td><td>".$cart_itm['description'];
            $message .= "</td><td>".$cart_itm['qty'];
            $message .= "</td><td>".$cart_itm['price'] ;
            $message .= "each</td><td></td></tr>";
        }

$message2 = <<<EOF

    </table>

<hr><table width="750" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="view-cart"><tr>
<td align="right"><b>Shipping: $ $shipping </b><br><b>Total: $ $total </b></td></tr></table>


</center>
</body>
</html>
EOF;
```

Comment: See my updated answer about the new syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is creating a string using the [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc); so everything that's after the first newline and before the identifier (`EOF` in your case) is considered part of that string, and no code will be executed inside of it besides variables and escape sequences for special characters.

As far as I know there is no solution besides ending the string just before the loop, then replacing all instances of `echo` with `$message +=` in the loop and finally creating a new string (using heredoc or conventional quotes and escaped newlines) after the loop and appending that new string to the `$message`.

Another (bad in my opinion) approach would be to put a placeholder for the loop's contents in the heredoc, then creating a new string that will hold the output of the loop and finally replacing the placeholder with that string.

Edit: for your updated code, note that the identifier `EOF1` should be at the beginning of a new line and be terminated with a semicolon.

Also, the identifiers aren't supposed to be unique, it's fine to use the same identifier for different strings, no need for `EOF1`, 2, etc.

Comment: Agreed, don't use heredoc for this. If you're interested in saving brain cells, at least just do string manipulation/concatenation with the `$message` variable. If you want to be a programming Bad Ass, then use templates like Twig or Smarty